# Python: Making large Dictionary is computationally intensive

Tags: python, dictionary

I am using a supercomputer, so memory is not an issue.  In fact, I am trying to exploit the large memory availability.

I am trying to read 177 Million lines from a file, parse each line into two short strings, and store those strings as a dictionary key tuple.  For the first 10 million lines or so, python reads over 1 million reads per 3 seconds.  This speed rapidly decreases and as far as I can tell, keeps getting longer.  So my process takes many fold longer than expected.

Is this because Python keeps readjusting the hash table size?
And if so, is there a way to declare the dictionary size to be 180 million?

```
targets={}
for line in open(blastInput):
    pieces = line.split()
    target = (pieces[0], pieces[1])
    #steps to calculate count omitted
    if not targets.has_key(target):
        targets[target] = 0
    targets[target] += count
```

Comment: When the dict gets roughly half full python resizes the dict, you might also find a collections.defaultdict faster instead of continually using has_key, use `targets = defaultdict(int)`

Comment: I would suspect that as it gets larger, the `targets.has_key()` call takes longer as more hash conflicts occur. Are the keys strings, or integers?

Comment: The key is a tuple of strings; the strings have variable length.  So you all are suggesting that targets.has_key(target) is the real guilty party here?
I'll see if I can modify the code to not use this.

Comment: @BAMF4bacon, use a defaultdict,  remove `if not targets.has_key(target):` and just `targets[target] += count` with `targets = defaultdict(int)`, you might also find the csv lib is also a better approach to read the file instead of manually splitting

Comment: You are reimplementing `collections.Counter`.

Comment: Also you might consider using `pandas` (or at least `numpy`), which should be faster to process such large files.

Comment: You should profile this. Better than trying to guess why it's slowing down.

Comment: You could also try building, for example, 180 million-item `dict`s as opposed to one `dict` with 180 million items.

Comment: That's a great suggestion, I think my question is "how do I make a 180 million-item dicts as opposed to one dict with 180 million items?"